# How to output ID from one resource which contains map variable

Tags: azure, terraform

I'm new in Terraform and I have silly question.I want to create NAT gateway and I need ID of one subnet:

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "this" {
  for_each = var.subnet_prefixes
  name                 = each.key
  resource_group_name  = var.subnetRGname
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.this.name
  address_prefixes     = each.value  
}
```

```
variable subnet_prefixes {
  type = map
  default = {
    "PublicSubnet"=["10.0.1.0/24"]
    "PrivateSubnet"=["10.0.2.0/24"]
  }
}
```

```
 output "publicsubnet" {
    value       = map ("private", azurerm_subnet.this.id)
    
     /* {
        for s in azurerm_subnet.this : s.name => private.id 
    } */
}
```

In first block I'm creating subnets from "subnet_prefixes" map variables.
But then I want to output only "PublicSubnet" ID so I can join it to my NAT gateway.

Is there any simple way to do this?
Thank you very much for your help.

EDIT:

Well I tried to do something about it and it kinda works while using count, but it is not what I expected:

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "this" {
  count                = length(var.subnet_prefixes)
  name                 = var.subnetnames[count.index]
  resource_group_name  = var.subnetRGname
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.this.name
  address_prefixes     = [var.subnet_prefixes[count.index]]
}
```

```
variable subnet_prefixes {
  type = list(string)
  default = ["10.0.1.0/24","10.0.2.0/24"]
}

variable subnetnames {
  type = list(string)
  default = ["SubnetA","SubnetB"]
}
```

```
 output "publicsubnet" {
    value       = azurerm_subnet.this.*.id
}
```

```
module "NAT" {
    source          = "./Modules/NAT"
    NATname         = "${var.RGName}-NAT"
    NATRGlocation   = module.Resource_Group.resource_group_location
    NATRGname       = module.Resource_Group.resource_group_name
    publicIPid      = module.VNET.publicIP
    publicsubnetID  = module.VNET.publicsubnet[0]
}
```

I'm just wondering, as you can see on main module i need to specify index of subnet, and I wanted to export only ID that somehow refers to name like "Public*". Is there any way to do it, or maybe could you please tell me how to improve this code?

Answer (score 0):

Since you've used `for_each` in your [azurerm_subnet](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/subnet) based on map of `var.subnet_prefixes`, you can refer to individuals subnets using **keys from the map**.

So public subnet id should be be:

```
 output "publicsubnet" {
    value  = azurerm_subnet.this["PublicSubnet"].id
}
```